# Best practice for sending messages to SignalR client and .NET core WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, signalr

I am looking at developing a client - server application whereby the client will send a message to the server via our API performing an action.  The web api (.NET) will hand off this message to a processing queue (Amazon queue at this stage) which will perform operations on it.  I would then like to send a message back to the client to indicate that the message has been processed etc.

The only way I can think of to do this is to have the processing queue which is not part of the web api send a HttpPost or HttpPut to the same API my SignalR hub is defined which will send send the messages out to the various clients.

However performance is an issue of this application so I'm hesitant to do another Http call from the backend server to the API just to then get a message sent.  Is there any other way I could look at getting these messages sent?

Comment: Are then client applications web applications? How are the messages in the queue processed, can you add code there?

Comment: You should implement a pub-sub model with your message queue. The API publishes a message to the queue to have some work done. A subscribed handler picks up the message and processes it. When it's done, it publishes a message to the queue that it completed the task, which your API would subscribe to. When it receives this message, it then publishes to your SignalR hub to notify the client.

Comment: Thank you Pratt.  That sounds potentially ideal to what I will will be wanting to do.  Will try it out

Comment: the client applications are web yes, but also potentiall desktop.  the messages will be processed via some sort of service not tied to the API at all so my query is how to get any notifications back to the client

Comment: @ChrisPratt I'm not aware of SQS offering a subscription service which means my Web Api would need to poll which means I would have a to have a thread or something on my API service constantly tied up?  Unless I'm missing something about SQS which offers a subscription service... ?